# gitignore does not ignore a file

Tags: git, gitignore

I have `config.ts` on `./packages/dashboard/src/core/config.ts` path and I would like to ignore in git.

I put those into gitignore file and nothing happens, the file is not ignored.

```
config.ts
./packages/dashboard/src/core/config.ts
packages/dashboard/src/core/config.ts
```

What is wrong? How to ignore this file to prevent changes in ?

Comment: what's the name of your gitignore file?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure it is not already tracked:

```
git rm --cached ./packages/dashboard/src/core/config.ts
```

Second, check the .gitignore does apply with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- ./packages/dashboard/src/core/config.ts
```

If the output of that command is not empty, that means the file is indeed ignored.